# How can I ensure that SSH remote BASH shell includes all PATH elements

Tags: linux, command-line, bash, ssh

So I'm trying to run a script remotely on ssh such as `ssh remote "~/bin/some_script.sh"` however the problem is that the script runs a command `vcs` that seems to not load when I try to just send the command via ssh, as opposed to ssh'ing into the remote and manually executing the command.

For clarity, the following output apears when I try

```
$ ssh remote "cd/...; vcs -x -...;"
bash: vcs: command not found
```

but it works when I do

```
$ ssh remote
remote$ vcs -x -...
remote$ //good output
```

I looked more into it and when I simple run

```
$ ssh remote "compgen -c | wc -l"
2611
```

vs

```
$ ssh remote
remote$ compgen -c | wc -l
3735
```

So clearly there are a lot of commands not being "loaded" when I just pass commands via ssh vs when I actually ssh into remote and execute commands. Any idea what is happening and how to overcome this?

Comment: is `ssh remote "whoami"` same as the direct login one?

Comment: Could it be that some commands are loaded by your .bashrc? Or that vcs is an alias defined in your .bashrc?
@Varon whoami is the same for me in both cases.

Comment: .bashrc is a good hint. Within an interactive ssh session, the scripts of the login shell are sourced in the environment. Calling some commands via ssh lacks this and results in different running environment.

Comment: Does this help?
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1198378/ssh-command-execution-doesnt-consider-bashrc-bash-login-ssh-rc

Answer (score 1):

Running `ssh remote "command"` opens a **non-interactive** shell, thus it doesn't source the regular files when opening. I dug deeper and found that clearly `$PATH` was missing some `/bins` when run non-interactively. My solution is to source the necessary folder when running the script `ssh remote "~/bin/some_script.sh"`

```
#!/bin/bash
. /etc/.../sourced_script.sh
# script
```

The only down side is you have to remember to source this script in every script you want to run remotely. Perhaps there is a more elegant solution where you can add this `. /etc/.../sourced_script.sh` to a startup script for non-interactive shells, but my n00b experience doesn't know if there are startup scripts for non-interactive shells.

Comment: this is stupid.  why should i have to figure out some script when ssh should just have an argument to source the proper scripts?

Answer (score 1):

This has been asked and answered many times elsewhere, including:

- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/940533/how-do-i-set-path-such-that-ssh-userhost-command-works
- https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/15207/dot-file-not-sourced-when-running-a-command-via-ssh
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/216202/why-does-an-ssh-remote-command-get-fewer-environment-variables-then-when-run-man

and many others.  I think the first one is the best answer I found in a few seconds of looking